# Set IFS to ignore whitespace in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to separate a pathname by the `/` character. I am trying to accomplish this using this line:

```
IFS='/' read -a FILEPATH_ARRAY <<< "$1"
```

This is part of a method called `retrieveParentDirectories` which then puts each element of FILEPATH_ARRAY into a string seperated by `/` after removing the last element (the file name that needs to go into the directory,) that I call like so:

```
TARGET_PARENT_DIRS=$(retriveParentDirectories "$path_to_target")
```

Where `$path_to_target` is the end path to the new location for the files I need to copy over.

The pathname it isn't working for, and which I eventually get a problem trying to copy into (because it isn't made correctly,) is any directory which includes spaces in the name. For example, if the directory was `path/to/some/important file which/im/interested/in`, it outputs `path/to/some/important/file/which/im/interested/in` as the eventual directory name.

What I need to figure out how to do would be to get the IFS to only separate on `/`, and to ignore white spaces. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Have you considered replacing spaces with some symbol like - and then removing it again as a temporary workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the file names, so I couldn't do that, fortunately I'm about to post an answer for any others who find this page with the same issue as I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your command to split the array was correct:

```
set -- "path/to/some/important file which/im/interested/in"
IFS='/' read -a FILEPATH_ARRAY <<< "$1"
```

When *using* the array, though, you need to properly quote the expansion. Consider the difference between

```
# Incorrectly produces 9 directory "names"
printf "%s\n" ${FILEPATH_ARRAY[@]}
```

and

```
# Correctly produces 7 directory names
printf "%s\n" "${FILEPATH_ARRAY[@]}"
```

---

It's rare to need to change the value of `IFS` outside of a single command. When you do, it's better to do it in an environment where the shell will revert the change for you, instead of having to save the old value yourself. (Note the `IFS=$OLDIFS` does not properly restore `IFS` if it was previously unset.)

Some examples:

```
# A subshell
(IFS=/; read -a myarray <<< "$text"; printf "%s\n" "${myarray[@]}")

# A function using the `local` command
my_function () {
    # myarray is global and remains set after my_function returns
    # IFS is only changed for the duration of the function 
    local IFS="/"
    read -a something <<< "$1"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer for any who find this page later on:

By setting the IFS variable before the read command, it is only a local change. The variable was breaking up just find, but when I looped through the array, the white spaces got broken up since IFS reverted back to its original delimiters.

The change needed was as follows, my read statement became the following three lines:

```
OIFS=IFS
IFS='/'
read -a FILEPATH_ARRAY <<< "$1"
```

Then, after I was finished building my path back up sans filename, I called the following command:

```
IFS=OIFS
```

to set it back so nothing else gets messed up.

Hopefully my hours of frustration on this problem can help someone else in the future!

Comment: You probably weren't quoting the array expansion properly when iterating over it.

Comment: I agree with @chepner -- if you're Doing It Right, you don't need this change. Show more code, and we can provide a better fix.

Comment: (By "better" -- there are concrete bugs that quoting on expansion fixes but setting an IFS value on expansion does not; for look at what happens to an array element containing a literal `*` for an example, keeping in mind that `mkdir -p '/tmp/*/hello'` is a completely valid command).